# Correct way of using 'intently' in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adverbs

I'll outline two ways of writing the same sentence below. Please guide me on which one is grammatically correct.

I wake up to a bear intently staring at me.

OR

I wake up to a bear staring intently at me

Comment: 'Waking up to a bear' sounds pretty unidiomatic no matter where you decide to put the adverb. But Google "intently staring at me" and "staring intently at me" to see whether pre- or post-participle positioning of 'intently' in say 'I woke up to find a bear [ ] staring [ ] at me' is used at all / more usual.

Comment: To intently stare where no bear has stared before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ***grammatically***, both your sentences stand, but the first sentence just sounds awkward. This was my first impression. When I checked [Gngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intently%20staring%2C%20staring%20intently&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintently%20staring%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaring%20intently%3B%2Cc0) I discovered that it gives clear preference to ***staring intently***

When I looked up ***adverbs of manner*** the examples that first appeared ***all*** placed the adverb of manner after the verb it determined. But I found other sites like [this one](https://www.really-learn-english.com/adverb-word-order.html#Adverbs_of_manner_), which have plenty examples with adverbs before the verb:

```
When there is a preposition before the verb’s object, place the adverb of manner either before the preposition, before the verb, or after the object.
 
Before the preposition
She listened secretly to their conversation.

Tom climbed weakly out of bed.
 
Before the verb
She secretly listened to their conversation.

Tom weakly climbed out of bed.
 
After the object
She listened to their conversation secretly.

Tom climbed out of bed weakly.
```

So I guess, in your situation it is usage that will give you the answer. Gngram shows instances of these usages (***intently*** before or after ***staring***) in written texts, but the difference between the two would convince me to use

> ***staring intently at me*** OR ***staring at me intently***

In fact, [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intently%20staring%20at%20me%2C%20staring%20intently%20at%20me%2C%20staring%20at%20me%20intently&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintently%20staring%20at%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaring%20intently%20at%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaring%20at%20me%20intently%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cintently%20staring%20at%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaring%20intently%20at%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaring%20at%20me%20intently%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows that ***staring at me intently*** is definitely the preferred option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a comprehensive reply! Thanks to your answer, I have better clarity on how I should use 'intently' in the given sentence.

Answer (score -2):

The question you are asking is in which place in the sentence is the adverb intently more correctly placed, before or after staring. I've read those alternatives several times and I have concluded that neither is more correct than the other.

This is not a grammar inquiry, rather it is a matter of style or taste. There are a couple of sources you can turn to for clarification:
”The Elements of Style" William Strunk, Jr. E.B. White; 1979 (or later); Macmillan Publishing Co., Inc.; New York & London
"The Elements of Grammar" Margaret Shertzer; 1986; Macmillian Publishing Co.Inc.; New York & London.

Comment: This needs some completion.

Comment: I was complete the answer that I began. My phone work excellently. However, while using the stacker exchange, my phone goes black. Nowhere on my phone (built in September 2020 and purchased in early November 2020) do I have this problem. After the "BLACKOUT" I am locked out of the exchange. I attempt to continue only to find one of two disturbing critiques. The first is negative in that I am prevented from my original work. How disconcerting. The second critique is even more disturbing. There is a l sly non-sentence the

Comment: Were you posting while driving or in a moving vehicle...? The syntax of your comment suggests that you were devoting your totally divided attention to the texting.